# Button's padding in navbar in Ionic2

Tags: android, html, ionic2

I've got a weirs UI issue. I've added a button to my navbar like it has been mentioned in the documentation but it does not look like in the example. There is this weird padding on the Android device:

[image]

code:
`

```
<ion-navbar>
  <ion-title>
    Location chooser
  </ion-title>

  <ion-buttons end>
    <button ion-button icon-only (click)="addButtonClicked()">
      <ion-icon name="add"></ion-icon>
    </button>
  </ion-buttons>
</ion-navbar>
```

Comment: what do you expect it to look like.  Is the weird padding on the "back" button or on the "+" button or both?  What have you tried already to change it?

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle for this? Because your code is working as expected on my machine. Which android version did you test?

Comment: In my opinion there is too much spacing between left edge of the screen and back button and right edge and plus button. I'm running it on the 4.2 so maybe that is a problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best way to get your desired effect but take a look at this sass.

```
// class for the back button
.back-button {
  padding-left: 4px;
}

// reference to add button
ion-header {
  ion-navbar {
    ion-buttons {
      button {
        // needed important.
        padding-right: 4px !important;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I determined back-button class by inspecting the element in chrome using `ionic serve`.  This is a good way to figure out what to change.

Comment: It is but when I'm using the Native components (loading from the SQLite and Storage) it does not allow me to get to this page. Thanks anyway, I will check if it works and let you know.